# Script to set formula every 25th row increasing date by 1 day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to set a formula into ColM every 25th row, starting with M4. The formula I'm setting needs to increase the date by one day each time.

The script I've previously used successfully on a different sheet, doesn't work after I've adapted it for this new sheet. I'm sure it's something simple I've missed, buy my dyslexia makes it very hard to see what.

I want to set formulas like this...

```
=FILTER(ZapUPDATE!T2:Z, ZapUPDATE!Q2:Q=date(2016,10,1), ZapUPDATE!R2:R="SUP") // Into M4
=FILTER(ZapUPDATE!T2:Z, ZapUPDATE!Q2:Q=date(2016,10,1)+1, ZapUPDATE!R2:R="SUP") // Into M29
=FILTER(ZapUPDATE!T2:Z, ZapUPDATE!Q2:Q=date(2016,10,1)+2, ZapUPDATE!R2:R="SUP") // Into M54
```

Etc and every 25th row down to M754. Here's the script...

```
function setFormulas() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for (var k = 0; k < 775; k++) {
    sheet.getRange(4 + 25*k, 13).setFormula('=FILTER(ZapUPDATE!T2:Z, ZapUPDATE!Q2:Q=date(2016,10,1)+' + k + ', ZapUPDATE!R2:R="SUP")');
  }
}
```

Link to the sheet is below. Any help gratefully received, thanks.

[Copy of sheet for Stack Overflow](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C2hrBqy5OIXxmWLxk-wzqkWfAq6rOpy1A3bK9Xa-4N4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function setFormulas() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheetSheet().getSheetByName('SUP10');
      var i = 0;
      for (var k = 4; k < 775; k = k + 25) {
        sheet.getRange(k, 13).setFormula('=FILTER(ZapUPDATE!T2:Z, ZapUPDATE!Q2:Q=date(2016,10,1)+' + i + ', ZapUPDATE!R2:R="SUP")');
        i++;
      }
    }
```

If you do `Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName())` you'll see that GAS considers another sheet (AVL) active — who knows why but in your case, I think, it can easily be overcome by using `getSheetByName()`.

Another thing is that iterating through every k value until it reaches 774 is really slow (and it creates 7k additional rows in your spreadsheet) — it hits the time limit and still doesn't finish the loop. Changing the loop's settings to `(var k = 4; k < 775; k = k + 25)` makes it run in 0.075 seconds.

And the last thing: you don't need to create a separate project for every single function you have :) You may write them all in one file or create a bunch of new .gs files inside a project — it'll be more convenient to work in such a fashion.

Hope it helps.